# SSLError when install gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I was going to install gcloud cli on my macbook running on macOS.
I run `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh` and met the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dl.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
```

I can access "dl.google.com" with my local browser.
When I run other gcloud commands, there is also this issue.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this command `gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True`?

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with @mxjecho, it works when running the below command to disable ssl verification:

```
gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like many of you, I also encountered the same problem when trying to install the Google Cloud SDK through my company's proxy server.

Initially, I attempted to bypass the issue using:

```bash
 ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True
```

Unfortunately, this method turned out to be unsuccessful.

After a fair amount of troubleshooting, I found a solution that worked for me:

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""
```

This is the method to disable SSL verification with the Python requests library.

I hope this solution can be of help to others facing the same issue. It feels great to be able to contribute back to this supportive community!